# Video not playing in bottom sheet - Android

Tags: java, android, video, android-videoview, bottom-sheet

I used video player libraries inside bottom sheet and it used to work fine.
Now I checked it and video is not playing. In some libraries video isnt loading, and some are playing audio keeping the video black.
I tried using default Video View and even it is not showing video.
Tried removing video from bottom sheet, and it worked fine.
Is it the problem with bottom sheet playing video?
How can it be avoided?

I am using following code:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="280dp"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">
        <TextView
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/text_view_sheet_title"
            android:textColor="@color/text_light"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:minHeight="50dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Video Preview"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/video_player"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_view_sheet_title" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Note: Video is playing fine when bottom sheet behavior is removed.**

Comment: Hi.did you find a solution for this by any chance?

Comment: Not yet @MiladMoosavi